# Looking for a good book to understand better how to write in language of logic and set theory.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I am looking for a book that would guide how read and write with logical and mathematical symbols because I sometimes dont really know how to put words into precise logical symbols in proofs for example even though I think I know the logic behind it. Propably someone would idwise to just do proofs and to exercises but I would like to find some material to guide as well. Is there some good introductory book for that?

Comment: Some introductory real analysis books start with a chapter on naive set theory and logic.  For example, the one I used for my intro to proof and real analysis class was [Steven Lay's book](https://www.amazon.com/Analysis-Introduction-Proof-5th-Steven/dp/032174747X).  It was pretty decent.  But if it's not at your university library I wouldn't recommend paying its ridiculous $134 cost just for the first two chapters.

Comment: Daniel Velleman, [How to prove it : A structured approach](https://books.google.it/books?id=sXt-ROLLNHcC&printsec=frontcover) (2nd ed, 2006).

Comment: David Gries & Fred Schneider, [A Logical Approach to Discrete Math](https://books.google.it/books?id=103UBwAAQBAJ&pg=PR4) (1993).

Comment: Ethan Bloch, [Proofs and Fundamentals : A First Course in Abstract Mathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=QJ_537n8zKYC&printsec=frontcover) (2nd ed, 2011).